# Test service worker in Test Cafe

Tags: javascript, typescript, service-worker, e2e-testing, testcafe

I would like to use TestCafe to check if my service worker is registered successfully. I can check that from browser console using the following code

`(await window.navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration()).active.scriptURL === 'PATH TO SERVICE WORK JS FILE'`

When trying to run this code from Test Cafe `ClientFunction`, the navigator object is empty.

How can I check if the service worker is loaded?

```
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

const getServiceWorker= ClientFunction(() => window.navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration());

fixture `My fixture`
    .page `http://www.example.com/`;

test('My Test', async t => {
    const serviceWorker = await getServiceWorker();
await t
      .expect(serviceWorker  && serviceWorker  !== null && serviceWorker.active).ok();

});
```

**Edit:**
I have created an issue on TestCafe Github here https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/7239

Answer (score 0):

Return the final value you want to test from the client function:

```js
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

const getScriptURL = ClientFunction(() => {
    return window.navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration()
        .then(serviceWorker => serviceWorker?.active?.scriptURL);
});

fixture `My fixture`
    .page `http://www.example.com/`;

test('My Test', async t => {
    const scriptURL = await getScriptURL();

    await t.expect(scriptURL).eql('PATH TO SERVICE WORK JS FILE');
});
```

If you still get a different value than expected, check the browser console in debug mode:

```js
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `New Fixture`
    .page `about:blank`;
    
test(`New Test`, async t => {
    await t.debug();
});
```

If the `value(await window.navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration()).active.scriptURL` doesn't match what you see in your app without TestCafe, then it looks like a bug. In this case, please create an issue in the [TestCafe repository](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe) and attach an example to it that reproduces this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It did not work. The service worker registration is empty object.

Comment: I see that you created an issue in the TestCafe repository. Thank you. I think it's worth leaving a link to it here: [Service Worker testing is not working](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/7239)